# Workbox - fetch with NetworkFirst not falling back to cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, service-worker, workbox

I'm writing a .Net MVC application and using Workbox.  I'm attempting to use the NetworkFirst strategy on a 'fetch' - within my service-worker I have the following:-

```
const API_ProductLoadData_URL = '/Product/LoadData';
const ProductLoadData_CacheName = 'product-index-loaddata';

const apiProductLoadDataCallHandler = new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: ProductLoadData_CacheName,
    networkTimeoutSeconds: 5,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
          maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60,
          maxEntries: 10,
      }),
    ]
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    API_ProductLoadData_URL,
    apiProductLoadDataCallHandler
);

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open(ProductLoadData_CacheName)
        .then(cache => cache.add(API_ProductLoadData_URL))
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(async function() {
        try {
            const fetchResponse = await fetch(event.request);
            if (fetchResponse.status === 404) {
                return await caches.match(event.request);
            } else {
                return fetchResponse;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return await caches.match(event.request);
        } 
    }());
});
```

Within my web page's code I have the following:-

```
const API_ProductLoadData_URL = '/Product/LoadData';
fetch(API_ProductLoadData_URL, {
})
.then(function (response) {
    var contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
    if (contentType && contentType.includes('application/json')) {
        return response.json();
    }

    throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
})
.then(function (json) {
    ...
)}
```

When I try the above using a CacheFirst or StaleWhileRevalidate strategy all looks OK (with a tweak to the code in the service worker) - i.e. the route behaves as you would expect - the fetch is intercepted and the code within the 'fetch' handler executes handing back the cached JSON

However, when I am offline, although I think the fetch route is wired up correctly, it still throws the 404 (not found) in my page - I would have expected the 404 to be handled within the 'fetch' (service worker) routing and the cached result be handed back to my page

A note - I am testing locally (on my machine) - to simulate offline, I am stopping IIS

Does anyone know why I can't get the service worker fetch event handler to hand me back the cached result if the network fails ?